# Making an SQL query executable from a Windows Form in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

I want to run my SQL (InsertUser) query

`INSERT INTO UserList (Username, [Password], CashDeposit, UserType) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`

from a windows form Using textboxes to enter parameters
causing changes to update into an MS Acess Database file I have made

I have made a table adapter and added the following code in my form

`Me.UserListTableAdapter.InsertUser(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text, CashDepositTextBox.Text, UserTypeTextBox.Text)`

There are no errors but the code does not cause any changes in the database file.The query works when executed from the query designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following code and it worked

`Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Public newConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Dalal Street\Dalal Street\Users.accdb"`

```
Public newConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Dalal Street\Dalal Street\Users.accdb"
```

`If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then`

```
            cn.Open()
        End IfDim cmd As New OleDbCommand


        Dim InsertMember As String = "INSERT INTO UserList (Username, [Password], CashDeposit, UserType,RegNo) VALUES  ('" & _UsernameTextBox.Text & "', '" & _PasswordTextBox.Text & "','" & _CashDepositTextBox.Text & "','" & _UserType.Text & "','" & _TextBox1.Text & "')"

        With cmd
            .CommandText = InsertMember
            .Connection = cn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (note this is C#):

```
public void executeNonQuery(string sql)
{           
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Globals.settings.dbLocation);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Here's a link to the MSDN article giving a better example and explanation: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How does the query get its parameters?

Comment: I do not want to use an entity model. Isn't there another way?

Comment: I don't know. You would need to post more of your code. I would suggest reading up on table adapters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233822.aspx